# Was this edit replacing code that had been removed rightfully rejected?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

My [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17802992) got rejected and I think it's probably just because my explanation for the edit was a bit misleading.

I actually re-added some code bits (Java import statements) that were modified by a previous editor. The exact original import statements are probably relevant to figuring out the answer to the question, if there is any.

The reviewer explained in the rejection that I should have instead commented. But actually the discussion with the OP in the comments led to the insight that the code example given by the OP should have remained as it was posted originally (except for the bad formatting, of course).

Is there anything I can do to get the edit through? The edit is still pending even though it has been rejected. Maybe because there has to be more than one review?

Comment: I'm not sure how relevant the imports are (or not), but you should have stated in the edit summary that they were already there in the first revision. Now it looks as if you just edit some code you think might be relevant.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that my edit summary was misleading. But I think the edit itself is legit, so wouldn't it be nice to somehow get the edit approved despite of the misleading summary? Ideally, there maybe should be a way to add an explanation to the original edit summary in a case like this.

Comment: The suggestion has been approved now. It's probably not worth worrying about like this when it's just the one rejection vote.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about one rejection vote. If the edit did get rejected and you think it shouldn't have been, then post about it here. (I don't know if you have permission to do this due to rep) but a better way would've been to roll back to the original version and then add any extras as a second edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The edit itself was fine, but the edit summary was not.

From what I read here, you didn't add import statements because "they seem to be relevant" (which would be a bad edit, since you shouldn't edit questions to fix code), you added them back because someone else (not OP) removed them - that's an important distinction.

You should not assume that anyone reviewing the edit has any of the context of the revision history or comments OP left (or, when relevant, that they know enough about the subject to understand the edit), so, until you have full edit privileges, it's important that you use the edit summary to fully justify why you're making the edit.

---

As pointed out in the comments, you only got one rejection vote, followed by 2 approval votes, which approved the edit - a suggested edit needs multiple votes (or a vote by the OP) to be either approved or rejected.

Comment: I asked after the first rejection vote and before the two approval votes and I didn't know how the edit review process exactly works. Also, I definitely learned the lesson about the importance of the edit summaries :) Thanks for the feedback, everyone!